# Why is my AWS Security group allowing traffic?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I thought I had an understanding of AWS security groups, but this doesn't make any sense.

I have a Lambda Function that is inside of my VPC.

It is assigned a security group (TestLambdaSG).

TestLambdaSG has inbound HTTP/HTTPS rules from IP 1.2.3.4/32

I can connect to my Lambda Function from my IP.  Why?

AWS says that security groups are restrictive by default, so I shouldn't be able to connect.  My Lambda function is an API that I created a test route that returns a "Success" message.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-security-groups.html

Comment: you created a test in local lambda function, its not a test from outside.

Comment: I can get to it through Postman on my machine, so I'm sending HTTP traffic from my IP to the Lambda function, right?

Comment: how did you test a lambda function ?

Comment: It's an API published to Lambda from Visual Studio, so I used Postman to hit the API path.

Comment: so you can connect to your API already ? how was response ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I don't understand.  I can connect to the API from my IP.  The response was just a text string that I return "From API" so that I know I can connect to it.  I thought the security group should block that.

Comment: make sure you got lambda logs, when you invoked API

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security group assigned to lambda only used to validate outgoing traffic , it is impossible to access the lambda directly through the socket connection. Therefore I dont think lambda security group's inbound rules are any useful.

But other services such as API gateway can invoke a lambda. An API gateway is publicly available by default when it is deployed.

That's why it's accessible from postman for you.